# Similarity of Dictionaries Using Cosine Similarity

Tags: python, similarity

I'm trying to use Cosine Similarity in Python to compare users, but can't seem to get it quite right.

```
from math import*


ratings={'Mr. Perfect': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 3, 8: 1, 9: 2},
         'The Progressive': {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3},
         'Mr. Villain': {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3}}




def square_rooted(x):

    return round(sqrt(sum([a*a for a in x])),3)

def cosine_similarity(x,y):

    input1 = {}
    input2 = {}
    vector2 = []
    vector1 =[]

    if len(x) > len(y):
        input1 = x
        input2 = y
    else:
        input1 = y
        input2 = x


    vector1 = list(input1.values())

    for k in input1.keys():    # Normalizing input vectors. 
        if k in input2:
            vector2.append(float(input1[k]))
        else :
            vector2.append(float(0))


    numerator = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(vector2,vector1))
    denominator = square_rooted(vector1)*square_rooted(vector2)
    return round(numerator/float(denominator),3)





print("Similarity between Perfect and Progressive")
print (cosine_similarity(ratings['Mr. Perfect'],ratings['The Progressive']))

print("Similarity between Villain and Progressive")
print (cosine_similarity(ratings['Mr. Villain'],ratings['The Progressive']))
```

Basically, found the formula here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980910/return-similar-score-based-on-two-dictionaries-similarity-in-python but I keep getting results of 1. Any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: `vector2.append(float(input1[k]))`
Replace by `vector2.append(float(input2[k]))`

Comment: Thanks tons! That looks like it did the trick. Do you think I should use Cosine or Jaccard Similarity?